# bindservice wont start the service and onserviceconnect wont call

Tags: java, android, react-native, service, bindservice

I`m trying to build and run a service for react native app, and after the service is running i need to call to some of the service methods what means that i need to get an instance of the running service so im trying to use bindservice().

the problem is that i when i`m calling bindservice() the onServiceConnected() and onStartCommand() wont start, on the other hand the onBind() in the service is starting.

all of the answers i`ve tried didnt help, this is part of them:

[ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected() never called after binding to started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246657/serviceconnection-onserviceconnected-never-called-after-binding-to-started-ser) 
[service onServiceConnected never called after bindService method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486692/onserviceconnected-never-called-after-bindservice-method) [ServiceConnection::onServiceConnected not called even though Context::bindService returns true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581440/serviceconnectiononserviceconnected-not-called-even-though-contextbindservic) 
[OnServiceConnected not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936225/onserviceconnected-not-getting-called)

Thanks in advance.

---

Here is the Service:

```
public class TestService extends Service {
    private LocalBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private Intent serviceIntent;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Log.i("service", "service starting!!@!@!@ ");

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("EXIT", "ondestroy!");
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("com.testapp.service.RestartTest");
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("com.testapp.service.RestartTest");
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    TesService getService() {
        return TestService.this;
    }
}

}
```

the package for the react native:

```
public class TestPackage implements ReactPackage {

private ReactApplicationContext applicationContext;
TestService runningService;
boolean mBound = false;

@Override
public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(
        ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
    runningService = new TestService(reactContext);
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(reactContext, runningService.getClass());
    reactContext.bindService(serviceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    modules.add(runningService.someMoudle());
    return modules;
}

/** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
runningService = ((LocalBinder) service).getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
}
```

The `AndroidManifest.xml` contains

```
<service
    android:name=".TestService">
</service>
```

Comment: You won't receive `onStartCommand` if you don't call `startService`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but from what I understand bindservice supposed to start the service.. but anyway I tried also to use startservice and it didn't start onserviceconnected

Answer (score 3):

Api.java

```
public class Api extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
     public KeyStoreApi(ReactApplicationContext reactContext){
        super(reactContext);
    }

    ....

    @ReactMethod
    public void connect(Promise promise){

        ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                ...
            }
        };

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(...);
        intent.setClassName(...);
        getReactApplicationContext().bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }
}
```

ApiPackage.java

```
public class KeyStoreApiPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext){
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext){
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
        modules.add(new Api(reactContext));
        return modules;
    }
}
```

i had same problem, then i found your question.
so, i want to share my solution.
it's work for me.

althouth, it's very late to you, 
I want to help someone.

Comment: You actually did a great job sir :D